# Multiple lines in AJAX POST request become one

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, multiline

I am trying to send a from's content over AJAX POST request, using jquery. Server is nodeJS built. My problem occurs when I sent a multilne message:

```
line1
line2

line3
```

becomes

```
line1,line2,,line3
```

On the server. This is the client side javascript/jquery code:

```
    function send() {
    var dataString = 'to=' + $("#to").val() + '&subject=' + $("#subject").val() + '&body=' + $("#body").val();
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
            url: "/sendMail",
                cache: false,
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
            location.reload();
                },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            location.reload();
            }
            });
    }
```

Then on the server side I have

```
var send = {call: function (request, response, params) {
    var subject = request.parameters['subject'];
    var body = request.parameters['body'];
    console.log(body);
    response.end();
    }
};
```

I wrote Request and Response, but they work ok - I get the right post parameters.
What could be the problem then?

Comment: try sending data in json format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX sends the data in one request string, You may use multiple request parameters (one for each line) or use some other format, like JSON. It could go like this :

```
...&line1=<line1>&line2=<line2>... and so on
```

Comment: Hey do you maybe know why I can't send charchters chars?

Comment: @Yotam, please be more specific . I'd suggest to add a new question so that other people can also help :)